# Right to Left in UWP based on condition?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am working on Windows 10 App and in my app, I get languages from the server and user can select any language from that. Now if the user selects Arabic, it works in RighttoLeft so I want to change it for all UI controls. Can someone suggest the easiest way to do that?

I am aware that we can use *FlowDirection* attribute for it. But there are many controls in my app and for each and every control, it will be difficult to change FlowDirection.

Comment: as far as I know from wpf - each control inherits the value from its parent - setting the Window/Page/UserControl FlowDirection to rtl will set all of them that way.

Comment: @gilmishal I am working on Windows Universal App for Phone and Tablet, not WPF. I tried to set FlowDirection for Page and it works as you said, but if there a way I can set this directly in App.xaml.cs file so I don't have to add the condition on every page?

Comment: it shouldn't be different, xaml is xaml - dependency property is a dependency property